# Ruby inject with index and brackets

Tags: ruby

I try to clean my Code. The first Version uses `each_with_index`. In the second version I tried to compact the code with the `Enumerable.inject_with_index-construct`, that I found [here](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/934794).

It works now, but seems to me as obscure as the first code.
Add even worse I don't understand the brackets around element,index in

```
.. .inject(groups) do |group_container, (element,index)|
```

but they are necessary

- What is the use of these brackets?
- How can I make the code clear and readable?

### FIRST VERSION -- WITH "each_with_index"

```
class Array

  # splits as good as possible to groups of same size
  # elements are sorted. I.e. low elements go to the first group,
  # and high elements to the last group
  # 
  # the default for number_of_groups is 4 
  # because the intended use case is
  # splitting statistic data in 4 quartiles
  # 
  # a = [1, 8, 7, 5, 4, 2, 3, 8]
  # a.sorted_in_groups(3) # => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 7], [8, 8]]
  # 
  # b = [[7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 7], [2, 8]] 
  # b.sorted_in_groups(2) {|sub_ary| sub_ary.sum } # => [ [[2, 8], [4, 5, 7]], [[7, 8, 9]] ]
  def sorted_in_groups(number_of_groups = 4)
    groups = Array.new(number_of_groups) { Array.new }
    return groups if size == 0

    average_group_size = size.to_f / number_of_groups.to_f
    sorted = block_given? ? self.sort_by {|element| yield(element)} : self.sort

    sorted.each_with_index do |element, index|
      group_number = (index.to_f / average_group_size).floor 
      groups[group_number] << element
    end

    groups
  end
end
```

### SECOND VERSION -- WITH "inject" AND index

```
class Array
  def sorted_in_groups(number_of_groups = 4)
    groups = Array.new(number_of_groups) { Array.new }
    return groups if size == 0

    average_group_size = size.to_f / number_of_groups.to_f
    sorted = block_given? ? self.sort_by {|element| yield(element)} : self.sort

    sorted.each_with_index.inject(groups) do |group_container, (element,index)|
      group_number = (index.to_f / average_group_size).floor
      group_container[group_number] << element
      group_container
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think this has a better answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733919/ruby-each-with-object-with-index

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> What is the use of these brackets?

It's a very nice feature of ruby. I call it "destructuring array assignment", but it probably has an official name too.

Here's how it works. Let's say you have an array

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]
```

Then you assign this array to a list of names, like this:

```
a, b, c = arr
a # => 1
b # => 2
c # => 3
```

You see, the array was "destructured" into its individual elements. Now, to the `each_with_index`. As you know, it's like a regular `each`, but also returns an index. `inject` doesn't care about all this, it takes input elements and passes them to its block as is. If input element is an array (elem/index pair from `each_with_index`), then we can either take it apart in the block body

```
sorted.each_with_index.inject(groups) do |group_container, pair|
  element, index = pair

  # or
  # element = pair[0]
  # index = pair[1]

  # rest of your code
end
```

Or destructure that array right in the block signature. Parentheses there are necessary to give ruby a hint that this is a single parameter that needs to be split in several.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 20):

```
lines = %w(a b c)
indexes = lines.each_with_index.inject([]) do |acc, (el, ind)|
  acc << ind - 1 if el == "b"
  acc
end

indexes # => [0]
```

Answer (score 1):

In case, someone is here from **2013+** year, you have `each_with_object` and `with_index` for your needs:

```rb
records.each_with_object({}).with_index do |(record, memo), index|
  memo[record.uid] = "#{index} in collection}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the use of these brackets?

To understand the brackets, first you need to understand how destruction works in ruby. The simplest example I can think of this this:

```
1.8.7 :001 > [[1,3],[2,4]].each do |a,b|
1.8.7 :002 >     puts a, b
1.8.7 :003?>   end
1
3
2
4
```

You should know how `each` function works, and that the block receives one parameter. So what happens when you pass two parameters? It takes the first element `[1,3]` and try to split (destruct) it in two, and the result is `a=1` and `b=3`.

Now, inject [takes two arguments in the block parameter](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject), so it is usually looks like `|a,b|`.  So passing a parameter like `|group_container, (element,index)|` we are in fact taking the first one as any other, and destructing the second in two others (so, if the second parameter is `[1,3]`, `element=1` and `index=3`). The parenthesis are needed because if we used `|group_container, element, index|` we would never know if we are destructing the first or the second parameter, so the parenthesis there works as disambiguation.

9In fact, things works a bit different in the bottom end, but lets hide this for this given question.)

Comment: I think each_slice will not work for me because with each_slice the last slice or group can be much smaller then the other groups and I need groups with almost the same size.

Comment: @ovhaag  `[1, 8, 7, 5, 4, 2, 3, 8].sort.each_slice(3)` results in `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 7], [8, 8]] `, that is your test case. Can you give me an example that not work, and then I can improve my answer?

Comment: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].sort.each_slice(3) # =>[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7]]`  not ok, last group too small
 
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].sort.each_slice(2) # =>[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7]]`  -- not ok, too many groups    

wanted: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].in_groups(3) # => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]`  -- ok 3 groups, size of biggest group - size of smallest group = 1

Comment: The slice size should be the population size divided by number of groups (also `self` is gratuitous): `sort.each_slice((size.to_f/number_of_groups).ceil).to_a`

Comment: @ovhaag Testing dbenhur tip also didn't worked for your last example. I'll remove the code from my answer to don't let it wrong, because I can't think in a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there already some answers given with good explanation. I want to add some information regards the clear and readable.

Instead of the solution you chose, it is also a possibility to extend Enumerable and add this functionality.

```
module Enumerable
  # The block parameter is not needed but creates more readable code.
  def inject_with_index(memo = self.first, &block)
    skip = memo.equal?(self.first)
    index = 0
    self.each_entry do |entry|
      if skip
        skip = false
      else
        memo = yield(memo, index, entry)
      end
      index += 1
    end
    memo
  end
end
```

This way you can call `inject_with_index` like so:

```
# m = memo, i = index, e = entry
(1..3).inject_with_index(0) do |m, i, e|
  puts "m: #{m}, i: #{i}, e: #{e}"
  m + i + e
end
#=> 9
```

**If you not pass an initial value the first element will be used, thus not executing the block for the first element.**