# Ruby `each_with_object` with index

Tags: ruby

I would like to do `a.each_with_object` with `index`, in a better way than this:

```
a = %w[a b c]
a.each.with_index.each_with_object({}) { |arr, hash|  
  v,i = arr
  puts "i is: #{i}, v is #{v}" 
}

i is: 0, v is a
i is: 1, v is b
i is: 2, v is c
=> {}
```

Is there a way to do this without `v,i = arr` ?

Comment: What is `hash` doing?

Comment: Why not just `each_with_object({}).with_index`?!

Comment: Yea, this is what I will use now that I know I can group values inside between || =)

Comment: Good one, @toro2.  Readers should note that here the block variables would be `|(e,h),i|`, where `e` is the element of the array `a`, `h` is the hash object being created and returned and `i` is the index.  `map.with_index` is another common use of `with_index`.  When you can't tack `with_index` to the end of an Enumerable method, you can precede it with `each_with_index`, rather than `each.with_index`.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Instead of

```
|arr, hash|
```

you can do

```
|(v, i), hash|
```

Comment: This is wrong, the answer below from @ka8725 is correct, it should be |(v, hash), i|, not |(v, i), hash|

Comment: I don't understand how a wrong answer can have so many votes 

Comment: both answers are correct as @sawa refers to `a.each.with_index.with_object` and  @ka8725's answer refers to `each_with_object({}).with_index`

Answer (score 80):

In your example `.each.with_index` is redundant. I found this solution:

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].each_with_object({}).with_index do |(el, acc), index|
  acc[index] = el
end
# => {0=>"a", 1=>"b", 2=>"c"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace your last line with

```
puts "i is: %d, v is %s" % arr.reverse
```

but, as @sawa suggested, disambiguating the array's argument is the thing to do here.  I just mention this as something to be stored away for another day.

Comment: Sure can :-) ... Sawa got me what I was looking for... I wanted a shortcut for assignment :-)